# WooCommerce display first name in email header

Tags: php, woocommerce

Been trying several different methods to display the first name of a customer in a new div I added to appear on the top of my emails, and I just keep getting errors in my code no matter what. This is what I currently have.

```
<?php // In case that you have only the $order object
    $user_data = get_userdata( $userid );
?>

<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
         <title><?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ); ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper-top">
             <p><?php echo 'Thank you for your order ' . $user_data->first_name . '!';?>!</p>
        </div>
```

Any idea what might make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at WooCommerce email template files. The first name is already used in default templates.
You can access the `$order` object:

```
<div id="wrapper-top">
    <p><?php echo 'Thank you for your order ' . $order->get_billing_first_name();?>!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that approach but it just brought up more errors:

Undefined variable: order came up for that $order->ger_billing_first_name() and there was a very lengthy fatal error about a Call to a member function get_billing_first_name() on null.

Comment: In the email_header.php template file.

Comment: You can add the code to the order email templates like customer-processing-order.php